# How to check if webpages contain X and then get their URL using wget

Tags: bash, awk, grep, wget

I wanted to spider a website and, if some text or a matching pattern is found in the HTML, get the URL(s) of the page(s).

Wrote the command

```
wget --recursive --spider site.com 2>&1 | sort | uniq | grep -oe 'www[^ ]*'
```

to get all the URLs thus far, but stuck as to how to output only those URLs that have a specified text. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*spider a website and, if some text or a matching pattern is found in the HTML*

This is impossible with `wget --spider`. [wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Download-Options.html) says that when you use `--spider`

> When invoked with this option, Wget will behave as a Web spider, which
> means that it will not download the pages, just check that they are
> there. For example, you can use Wget to check your bookmarks:
>
> `wget --spider --force-html -i bookmarks.html`
>
> This feature needs much more work for Wget to get close to the
> functionality of real web spiders.

`wget` with `--spider` option does fetch response headers, which you can print following way

```
wget --spider --server-response http://www.example.com
```

which will contain information about file, for example [Content-Length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length) informing about file size, but not file content itself.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as long as wget finds and follows links in recursive spidering, it actually reads and makes available all contents... It was a wrong tool for my task then.